# Does tomcat creates thread even if it returns 404 error

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, web, containers

In case of 404 error,does tomcat create Thread for this request?In other word what does tomcat do first? 1. Finds the corresponding servlet first then create thread or first creates thread then try to find the corresponding servlet?

Comment: Why do you care?

Answer (score 0):

First servlet is found then thread is created. 404 error is handled by implicit threads of container.